# What are the uses of force - release statements?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

From a hardware point of view, what do `force` and `release` statements model? What are the uses of these statements?

Answer (score 10):

The force/release statements are generally used to aid in **simulations**.

One scenario is to avoid **X-propagation in gate** simulations.  The RTL code sometimes contains registers without asynchronous resets.  Although the RTL simulations will run cleanly, gate simulations often do not.  Either the X's never get resolved, or they take so many cycles to resolve so as to make simulations take an impractical amount of time to run.  By forcing and releasing a random known value into the register during reset, the simulation is allowed to proceed cleanly and complete in a timely manner.

Another scenario involves **large counters**.  For example, to see a 32-bit counter roll over, it requires 4 billion cycles.  Typically, you want it to roll over several times in one simulation.  Again, this could take an impractically long time to simulate.  The force/release can be used to deposit a random value into the counter close to the roll-over value.

Another scenario involves boosting **code coverage** results.  It can be difficult to achieve 100% coverage on all metrics, especially when using IP which can not be modified.  The force can be used to toggle an unused signal.

The force/release should be used sparingly and only when you are convinced it is valid to do so.

Answer (score 7):

Based on IEEE Std 1364-2005, the *force* procedural continuous assignment statement shall override all procedural assignments to a variable or net. The *release* procedural statement shall end a procedural continuous assignment to a variable or net. The value of the variable shall remain the same until the variable is assigned a new value through a procedural assignment or a procedural continuous assignment.

For example:

```
module test;  
    reg a, b, c, d;
    wire e;
    and and1 (e, a, b, c);

    initial begin
      $monitor("%d d=%b,e=%b", $stime, d, e);
      assign d = a & b & c;
      a = 1;
      b = 0;
      c = 1;
      #10;
      force d = (a | b | c);
      force e = (a | b | c);
      #10;
      release d;
      release e;
      #10 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

In the example above *and* gate `and1` is patched to work as *or* gate. If you simulate it, you'd get following results:

> Results:
>   00 d=0,e=0
>   10 d=1,e=1
>   20 d=0,e=0

Without *force* statement, for `t = 10`, `e` should be equal to 0 (since `1 & 0 & 1 = 0`). Using *force* statement overrides result of `and1` and force `e = 1`. But as soon as *release* is applied to `e`, the value is change to 0 (the functionality of and gate is restored).

In the example above you can also see that *force*/*release* can be applied both to regs (`d`) and wires (`e`). This statements are used in testbenches, when you want to force determined value in reg or wire.